# Does datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime()) in Python give me a timezone-aware value?

Tags: python, unix, datetime, timezone, epoch

I am using calls such as this in Python 3.4:

```
x = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(somefilename))
y = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(somefilename))
```

Will `x` and `y` be timezone-aware, as per [the definition of that term in the datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html)? Does this vary between platforms? I assume that in theory the ctime and mtime of a file are measured against the seconds since the epoch in UTC, so the answer should be yes?

If so, is that true across all/most POSIX platforms? Specifically, is it true on modern Linux/OS X?

If not, is there a better way to handle this? How can I get timezone-aware ctime and mtime data? What timezone do platforms use for expressing/storing ctime and mtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OSX, at least, `os.path.getctime` returns a TZ-naive datetime in the system's timezone.

```
$ date
Mon Jun  8 15:08:40 PDT 2015

$ touch new_file
$ python  
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import os
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime('new_file'))
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 15, 8, 42)
>>> print datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime('new_file')).tzinfo
None
```

`time.timezone` will give you the local timezone offset in seconds, **not accounting for DST**. The [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz/) library will probably be very useful to you.

Comment: Check the file's `tzinfo` attribute isn't very useful as the `fromtimestamp` function allows you to pass in the timezone as a `tzinfo` instance. Without it, it just uses the local timezone. I'm guessing throughout the `datetime` module `None` must represent "just use the local timezone".

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.getctime()` returns a float that represents "seconds since epoch" (values returned by `time.time()`) -- it is not a datetime object naive or otherwise.

`datetime.fromtimestamp()` returns a naive datetime object representing local time *unless* you pass the explicit tzinfo object as a second parameter, [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30731530/4279).